# Error when running msbuild /t:restore under Jenkins to restore nuget packages

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package-restore

The error we get during the build is:

```
Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
An error occurred while sending the request.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
```

If I remote into the build machine and pull the source from source control, I can build and have VS restore the nuget packages without an issue.

I can also open https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json in a browser on the machine, so I don't believe it's a network/firewall issue.

Note that Jenkins is running under SYSTEM LOCAL

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have had to do with Win7 having TLS 1.2 disabled. Ran this on the machine and the error stopped:

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f /reg:32
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f /reg:64
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:64
```

Note that I think you need to add to both 32 and 64 bit registries because msbuild may run in either one depending on the build